# Conversão especificada não é válida no ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, conversão-de-tipo

O erro de conversão especificada não é válida acontece no código:

```
if (command.ExecuteScalar() == DBNull.Value)
{
    resultados[j2][i2] = 0;
}
else 
{
    resultados[j2][i2] = (double)(decimal)command.ExecuteScalar(); /* <<---- */
}
```

A query que estou executando no mysql é:

```
SELECT IFNULL(AVG(VL_M4000010),0) 
FROM HT_MA4_ESS_SEG 
WHERE YEAR(TS_SAMPLETM) = 2015 
    AND MONTH(TS_SAMPLETM) = 1 
    AND TIME(TS_SAMPLETM) 
    BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '00:15:00'
```

O resultado do *query* via MySQL Workbench é `0`.

Já tentei fazer a conversão sem o `(decimal)` apenas com o `(double)`, de forma que ficaria `(double)command.ExecuteScalar();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou considerar que o tipo de `resultados` é `double`. Então faça uma [conversão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDouble_System_Object_) em vez de um *cast*:

```
Convert.ToDouble(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/ConvertResult.cs).

Não tem porque usar o `TryParse()` aqui porque esse dado consegue ser convertido sempre.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Outra alternativa é utilizar o `Double.TryParse`.

```
string value;
double number;

value = Double.MinValue.ToString();
if (Double.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of a Double.", 
                     value);

value = Double.MaxValue.ToString();
if (Double.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of a Double.",
                     value);
```

Exemplo retirada de:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx